# How can I stop this document attached event listener from emitting duplicate events?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, addeventlistener

I'd like for a game to fire events upon key presses, but when I navigate away from and back to the game page the event listener fires twice. I found another issue suggesting I remove the listener before adding it, but that isn't helping.

The listener is added during `mounted`

```
mounted() {
        this.setupInputListener();
    },
```

And the keydown event listener is added to the document

```
        keydownListener() {
            const action = handleKeyDown(event.key);
            if ( action ) {
                this.SEND_INPUT({
                    gameId: this.gameId,
                    action: action
                });
            }
        },
        setupInputListener() {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keydownListener);
            document.addEventListener('keydown', this.keydownListener);
        }
```

How can I prevent this keydown listener from emitting duplicate events?

Comment: Remove the event listener in the component’s beforeDestroy lifecycle hook.

Comment: What do you consider a duplicate? Perhaps you're looking to debounce? Or as Terry mentioned are you accumulating multiple listeners?

Comment: Yes I'm accumulating multiple listeners using this method. This is NuxtJS. I'll try removing the listener as part of the lifecycle hook but it seems like any pre-existing listener should still be removed using the current method.

Comment: Huh it turns out Terry's suggestion was right. Odd that the removal works in the ```destroy``` part of the lifecycle but not if triggered right before in the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add an event listener multiple times, that will cause it to fire once or many times. To avoid this, try using `onkeydown`. Once we do this we no longer need the `removeEventListener`. For example, something like this should work:

```js
keydownListener() {
        const action = handleKeyDown(event.key);
        if (action) {
            this.SEND_INPUT({
                gameId: this.gameId,
                action: action
            });
        }
    },
    setupInputListener() {
        document.onkeydown = () => {
            this.keydownListener;
        }
    }
```

**Hoped this helped!**

Comment: This is a more elegant solution